# How create object which requires itself in constructor? (PHP)

Tags: php, class, oop

Today I recalled question, which was asked me on interview two years ago.

And I want to resolve it, because it bothers me very much.

So, here is my PHP class:

```
class A
{
    function __construct(A $aObject)
    {
        $aObject->getValue();
        return;
    }

    function getValue()
    {
        echo 'Success';
    }
}
```

How I can create object of this class? But we can't change this class.

Comment: Create a class B which extends A and overwrites A's construct method and  create via new  A(new B());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, the most trivial one is using [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor`](https://secure.php.net/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor):

```
$a = new A((new ReflectionClass("A"))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor());
```

Another solution would be extending the class and overloading the constructor there:

```
class B extends A {
    function __construct() {}
}
$a = new A(new B);
```